# How to use WHERE loop based on select statment in plsql [solution related to connect by prior]

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

We have a database in which many records are merged. And it's not unusual for a person to have many merged ids. I'd like to create a table that keeps track of every person's first id and their most recent id.  I'm assuming that the best way to do this but I'm not sure how to write the WHILE loop.

Original table looks like this:

```
Table1  
old_id  new_id  
001     001  
002     002  
001     003  
004     004  
003     005  
005     006
```

First, I run

```
CREATE Table2 AS  
SELECT *  
FROM Table1   
WHERE old_id = new_id  
;
```

After running that, I should have

```
Table2  
old_id  new_id  
001     001  
002     002  
004     004
```

Then the statement I want to loop until there are no more updates to do is:

```
UPDATE Table2  
SET new_id = (SELECT b.new_id  
              FROM Table1 AS a  
                JOIN Table1 AS b ON b.old_id = a.new_id  
              WHERE b.old_id != b.new_id)  
;
```

until I get to the resulting table that I'm trying to build:

```
Table2  
old_id  new_id  
001     006  
002     002  
004     004
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Look into `connect by prior`  It allows you to crawl a hierachy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( old_id, new_id ) AS
SELECT '001', '001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '002', '002' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT '001', '003' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '004', '004' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '003', '005' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '005', '006' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( old_id, new_id ) AS
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( old_id ),
       new_id
FROM   table1
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH old_id = new_id
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR new_id = old_id;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```

**Output**:

```
OLD_ID NEW_ID
------ ------
001    006    
002    002    
004    004
```

**As a view**:

As per @xQbert's suggestion, you could create it as a view rather than as a table so it will stay up to date.

```
CREATE VIEW View_Of_Table1( old_id, new_id ) AS
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( old_id ),
       new_id
FROM   table1
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH old_id = new_id
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR new_id = old_id;
```

Comment: Nice!  but why not just create it as a view so it remains up-to-date :P

Comment: @xQbert The OP was talking about creating a table so I just did that but give me a moment and I'll add a view to my answer.